# How to use Lambda@Edge to detect user country and redirect to localised subfolder like /pt?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-lambda-edge

I am using the following Lambda@Edge code but don't know how to go about it.

The following code makes Subdirectory root index working on Cloudfront.

**Does Cloudfront offer origin country in request?**

```
'use strict';

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {

    // Extract the request from the CloudFront event that is sent to Lambda@Edge 
    var request = event.Records[0].cf.request;

    // Extract the URI and params from the request
    var olduri = request.uri;

    // Match any uri that ends with some combination of 
    // [0-9][a-z][A-Z]_- and append a slash
    var endslashuri = olduri.replace(/(\/[\w\-]+)$/, '$1/');

    //console.log("Old URI: " + olduri);
    //console.log("Params: " + params);
    //console.log("Mid URI: " + miduri);

    if(endslashuri != olduri) {
        // If we changed the uri, 301 to the version with a slash, appending querystring
        var params = '';
        if(('querystring' in request) && (request.querystring.length>0)) {
            params = '?'+request.querystring;
        }
        var newuri = endslashuri + params;

        //console.log("No trailing slash");
        //console.log("New URI: " + newuri);

        const response = {
            status: '301',
            statusDescription: 'Permanently moved',
            headers: {
                location: [{
                    key: 'Location',
                    value: newuri
                }]
            }
        };
        return callback(null, response);
    } else {
        // Match any uri with a trailing slash and add index.html
        newuri = olduri.replace(/\/$/, '\/index.html');

        //console.log("File or trailing slash");
        //console.log("New URI: " + newuri);

        // Replace the received URI with the URI that includes the index page
        request.uri = newuri;

        // Return to CloudFront
        return callback(null, request);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Cache Behavior settings, whitelist the header `CloudFront-Viewer-Country` for forwarding to the origin.  The origin doesn't need it, but once you configure this, then you have access to the viewer country in a Lambda@Edge Origin Request trigger:

```
const cc = (request.headers['cloudfront-viewer-country'] || [ { value: 'XX' } ])[0].value;
```

Replace `'XX'` with whatever value you want to assign to the constant `cc` if CloudFront can't determine a country code -- e.g. your default.

You can't access the country from a Viewer Request trigger,  but Origin Request is a better choice anyway -- responses (the redirects) from this trigger can be cached, meaning the trigger fires less often.  CloudFront will automatically cache a different copy of the page for each country code and serve it only to viewers in the same country.

Comment: Is this the only piece of code required to make this work with what I have above? Do I potentially need a second Lambda function for this? Please advise.

Comment: Once you configure the cache behavior to whitelist that header, this is all you need to add to an existing function in order to get the country code into the variable `cc`.  You'll need to modify your code, in order to make use of the value.